# How to render this stereopanorama for VR in unreal engine4

Tags: unreal-4, virtual-reality, htc-vive

How to render this stereopanorama for VR in unreal engine4

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's 2 [equirectangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) images stacked one on top of the other. The top is the left eye, and the bottom is the right eye.

What you need to do is place the camera inside a sphere and project the top half of the image onto that sphere and render it for the left eye, then project the bottom half onto the sphere and render it for the right eye.

To do that, the texture coordinates you use should map the x-coordinate of the texture map to longitude and the y-coordinate to latitude. Here are the equations used to do that:

> x = (λ - λ0) * cos(φ1);
>
> y = (φ - φ1);

where:

> λ is the longitude of the location to project;
>
> φ is the latitude of the location to project;
>
> φ1 are the standard parallels (north and south of the equator) where the scale of the projection is true;
>
> λ0 is the central meridian of the map;
>
> x is the horizontal coordinate of the projected location on the map;
>
> y is the vertical coordinate of the projected location on the map.

So to get your texture coordinates for each vertex, you can do the following:

```
GLfloat getThetaForXandY(const GLFloat x, const GLfloat y)
{
    GLfloat result  = atan2f(x, y);
    if (result < 0.0f) {
        result += M_PI * 2.0;
    }
    
    return result / (M_PI * 2.0);
}

GLfloat getPhiForA(const GLfloat a)
{
     return acos(a) / M_PI;
}
```

Here `a` is a value between 0 and 1 and can just be the `y` coordinate of your vertex. (Note that the code's `theta` is the equation's `lambda`.)

Comment: Question: How big the sphere needs to be? I can conclude that the center od the sphere will be camera position.

Comment: @HimanshuChaudhary As big as you want it to be.  As long as the camera is at the center, size is irrelevant— this is essentially a spherical skybox.  The things to consider when determining the size is that the radius should be within the camera's near & far clip distances, and if you have any other elements in the scene, the sphere should encompass them _(though you could make this consideration irrelevant by forcing the sphere's render order to be 1st and having it not draw to the depth buffer)_.

Comment: As much as I understood the answer it puzzles me how to achieve the same using blueprint. This is what I constructed from my findings in unreal engine forums [material-blueprint](http://imgur.com/a/nOgUg) and the result looks like this on the [viewport](http://imgur.com/a/nOgUg).

Will it work with headset?

Comment: It seems like you're using the entire input image for the texture. You need to use just the top half or just the bottom half. For example, the 4th image down looks like it's showing the seam between the 2 images. That should never happen because you should only be sending one of the images to the shader for one eye.

Comment: For that purpose I have that material blueprint. It is the very last item in the link.

Comment: Oh, one other thing. While Slipp is right about the sphere being any size, it is assumed that the vertices are on the unit sphere, and hence, between -1.0 and 1.0 for all coordinates. I've not used blueprint, so I don't know how that works, Sorry if I misunderstood something there.